# Cannot send signal SIGINT to a process created inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I have two scripts:

```
### firstScript.sh ###
trap 'kill $pid;' SIGINT
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
        echo "$i x $1 = `expr $i \* $1`"
        sleep 10 &
        pid=$!
        wait $!
done
```

And:

```
### secondScript.sh ###
./firstScript.sh 5 &
pid=$!
echo $pid
ps
for (( i=0; i<8; i++))
do
        kill -2 $pid
        sleep 3
done
```

The 2nd script will call the first script in background mode and send it a SIGINT signal every 3 seconds. However, it doesn't work at all.

I tried run the 1st script in background  with `./firstScript.sh 5 &` and send a signal with `kill -2 %1` or `kill -2 <pid>` (with the pid was obsevred after creating the 1st script) and both of them worked fine.

However, I couldn't do it by the script.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: `trap 'kill $pid;' SIGINT` in first script but which `pid` it will kill?

Comment: $pid is the PID of the sleep process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to make this work as it appears you intend it to, use a different signal, such as SIGUSR1:

```
### firstScript.sh ###
trap 'kill $pid;' SIGUSR1
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
        echo "$i x $1 = `expr $i \* $1`"
        sleep 10 &
        pid=$!
        wait $!
done
```

And:

```
### secondScript.sh ###
./firstScript.sh 5 &
pid=$!
echo $pid
ps
for (( i=0; i<8; i++))
do
        kill -USR1 $pid
        sleep 3
done
```

I have spent some time trying to figure out why SIGINT is behaving the way it does, but have not been able to yet.

Comment: Excellent! But the reason why SIGINT (and SIGQUIT either) does not work is still a mistery :)

Comment: Yeah - I would really like to come back to this when I have a little more time.  I would suspect that with the INT signal, bash may be ignoring it altogether when the background job is created from within a script instead of within an interactive session.